# Swift - print each item in an array to different rows on a UILabel

Tags: swift

I am completely new to Swift but am loving my journey so far. I was wondering if anyone could help me with a slight issue of mine.
I am currently trying to print each item in an array to a different row on a UILabel.
I should be using a for loop but I am wondering how to structure the inside of the loop so that each item in the array prints on a separate line of the label.

As a bonus question, would a label even be the best way to display this? (Especially if the array has a lot of items). Maybe a ScrollView?

Thanks in advance for any responses. All help is appreciated.

Comment: From what you are describing you should be using a tableview.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be the following.

```
// Label will show as many lines as needed
label.numberOfLines = 0

// Join strings with new line characters so each string is a separate line
label.text = arrayOfStrings.joined(separator: "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
This looks perfect. I will give it a shot when I get home from work.
From your personal experience, would a UILabel be a good way to display many lines of text or does Xcode have something more preferrable?

Comment: If you're just displaying then `UILabel` is prefect. If you need to display and edit then `UITextView` would be needed.